# Django form dynamic required checklist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ModelForm that I want to extend with a dynamic list of checklist items. So a user can only create an instance of my model when he ticked all checkboxes and the checkboxes are actually not part of the Model itself.

The checklists and coresponding checklist items are dynamically created and will change in future.

```
class Checklist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ChecklistItem(models.Model):
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(Checklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    details = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

So at the end of the form it should look something like this (similar to accepting the Terms of Service):

[desired form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5NaN.png)

I cant come up with a solution of how to group the Items per Checklist.

If I want to only list every item, without caring what Checklist it belongs to I could do:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = SomeModel
    fields = ['some_attribute', 'another_attribute']


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for checklist in Checklist.objects.all():
        for item in checklist.checklistitem_set.all():
            self.fields[item.text] = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
```

But thats not what I like. I also dont know how I could access the details attribute of the ChecklistItem (for example for a tooltip) doing it this way.

Does anybody know about an elegant solution on how to implement this?

Comment: I think `required=True` does not mean the item has to be checked, you will need to validate that as well.

Comment: I you just call your CheckListItems to your form, edit they widget to do anything you like and then validated ise using clean function in your models, so when you run form.is_valid he will run your clean function and check your logic, if pass you save your models, if dont you raise some error and handle it

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem required=True did indeed prevent me from submitting my form. With required=False I was able to submit the form without checking the boxes